# NullpointerException allthough reference is passed

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx, fxml

**Irc client which can make multiple connections to different irc servers.**
Each tab represents a server connection. I want a connection closed when its tab is closed.
When i start a connection using the menuitembutton event i construct a serverConnection object, **passing it to the main controller *(serverConnection con)* before** i launch the communication method in a new thread.

Now the problem is that when onTabClose event is fired i get a **nullpointerexception** when i use the **reference from the main controller** *to change a flag so that the method running in the thread will return and eventually stop instead of using the deprecated thread.stop() method. (Keep in mind that a thread using that object is already running)*

**Why do i get that exception when i have already passed a reference?** (garbage collector can't have touched the object since it's used in the thread and main controller reference)

serverConnection class

```
package jircclient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class serverConnection
{
    //VARIABLES
    public clientInfo client;
    private String server_to_connect;
    private String channel_to_connect;
    private String serv_resp;
    private int port;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedWriter writer;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private ArrayList<channel> channels;
    public boolean threadExitFlag = false;

    //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    public serverConnection() {}

    //FULL CONSTRUCTOR
    public serverConnection(clientInfo clientInfo, String server_to_connect, int port, String channel_to_connect) throws IOException
    {
        this.client = clientInfo;
        this.server_to_connect = server_to_connect;
        this.port = port;
        this.channel_to_connect = channel_to_connect;

        try
        {    
            //Creating socket connection
            this.socket = new Socket(this.server_to_connect,port);

            //Socket output writer
            writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

            //Socket input writer
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            serv_resp = null;

            System.out.println("Connection established.");
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException exc)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+ exc.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException exc)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+ exc.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("Closing connection.");
            socket.close();
        }
    }

    public Consumer<String> messageCallback ;

    public void setMessageCallback(Consumer<String> messageCallback) {
        this.messageCallback = messageCallback ;
    }

    //server response getter
    public String getServerResponse()
    {
        return serv_resp;
    }

    public void exitThread()
    {
        this.threadExitFlag = true;
    }

    //Introduction to server and listen
    public void startCommunication() throws IOException
    {
        //
        this.socket = new Socket(this.server_to_connect,port);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));  
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
        serv_resp = null;
        //

        writer.write("NICK " + client.getClientNickname() + "\r\n");
        writer.write("USER " + client.getClientLogin() + " 0 * : " + client.getClientRealName() + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();

        while ((serv_resp = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(serv_resp);
            if (messageCallback != null) 
                messageCallback.accept(serv_resp);

            if (serv_resp.indexOf("004") >= 0)
            {
                break;
            } 
            else if (serv_resp.indexOf("433") >= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");
                return;
            }
        }

        //Get channel list
        writer.write("LIST \r\n");
        writer.flush();

        //Join desired client
        writer.write("JOIN " + channel_to_connect + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();


        //keep listening
        while ((serv_resp = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //check if running thread should terminate
            if(threadExitFlag)
            {
                System.out.println("THREAD FLAG POINT");
                writer.write("QUIT :Bye..");
                socket.close();
                return;
            }

            if (messageCallback != null) 
                messageCallback.accept(serv_resp);
            if (serv_resp.startsWith("PING "))
            {
                this.pingPong();
            } else
            {
                System.out.println(serv_resp);
            }
        }
    }

    //Ping respond
    public void pingPong() throws IOException
    {
        writer.write("PONG " + serv_resp.substring(5) + "\r\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
```

mainController class

```
    package jircclient.FXML;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import jircclient.serverConnection;

public class FXMLmainController implements Initializable
{  
    //VARIABLES
    private connectionThreadFactory connectionThreadFactory;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    private int tabCounter = 0;
    public serverConnection con;

    //CONTROLLER VARIABLES
    @FXML
    TextArea txt;
    @FXML
    TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private void connectServerMenuButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked connectServerButtonAction!");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/jircclient/FXML/FXMLserver.fxml"));

        try 
        {
            Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 200);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Server Info");
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

            FXMLserverController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.initData(stage, this);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLserverController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   
    }

    @FXML
    private void onTabCloseEvent(Event event)
    {
        //Event type instead of ActionEvent because the latter didnt work
        //i must be able to get a reference to the serverConnection object of the associated tab
        //i have to keep a list of the tab ids and the thread objects so i can set the threadExitFlag to TRUE
        System.out.println("CLOSE");
        System.out.println("FLAG: "+ con.threadExitFlag);
        con.exitThread();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        System.out.println("Initialize in controller!");
        connectionThreadFactory = new connectionThreadFactory("Server Connection");
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, connectionThreadFactory);        
    }

    //setters - getters
    public connectionThreadFactory getConnectionThreadFactory()
    {
        return connectionThreadFactory;
    }

    public ExecutorService getExecutorService()
    {
        return executor;
    }

    public int getTabCounter()
    {
        return tabCounter;
    }

    public void setTabCounter(int tabCounter)
    {
        this.tabCounter = tabCounter;
    }

    public void increaseTabCounter()
    {
        tabCounter++;
    }
}
```

serverController class - starts when connectServerMenuButtonAction is fired and opens new window-stage

```
package jircclient.FXML;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jircclient.clientInfo;
import jircclient.serverConnection;

public class FXMLserverController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable
{
    //PARENT VARIABLES - REFERENCES
    Stage stage;
    FXMLmainController parentController;

    //CONTROLLER VARIABLES
    @FXML
    TextField ircServerField, port, nicknameField, loginField, realNameField;
    @FXML
    PasswordField passwordField;

    public void initData(Stage stage, FXMLmainController parentController)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
        this.parentController = parentController;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        System.out.println("serverController reporting in!");
    }

    @FXML
    private void connectButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
    {
        //get info from text fields - initialize serverConnection
        clientInfo clientInfo = new clientInfo(this.realNameField.getText(), this.nicknameField.getText(), this.loginField.getText());
        serverConnection serverConnection = new serverConnection(clientInfo, ircServerField.getText(), Integer.parseInt(port.getText()), "#linux");
        serverConnection.setMessageCallback(message -> 
            Platform.runLater(() -> ((TextArea) parentController.tabPane.lookup("#txt")).appendText(message+"\n")));

        //prepare thread
        Thread serverThread = parentController.getConnectionThreadFactory().newThread(() -> {
            try
            {
                serverConnection.startCommunication();
                System.out.println("Terminating Thread...");
            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLmainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

        //add server tab
        parentController.tabPane.getTabs().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/jircclient/FXML/FXMLtab.fxml")));
        parentController.tabPane.getTabs().get(parentController.getTabCounter()).setText(ircServerField.getText());
        parentController.increaseTabCounter();

        //start thread-communication
        serverThread.setDaemon(true);
        parentController.getExecutorService().execute(serverThread);

        parentController.con = serverConnection;
        System.out.println("CON IFNO"+ parentController.con.threadExitFlag);
        //close window
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    private void cancelButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        //close window
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

fxml snippet for the #onTabCloseEvent event

```
<Tab xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="jircclient.FXML.FXMLmainController" onClosed="#onTabCloseEvent">
```

stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1762)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1645)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TabPaneBehavior.canCloseTab(TabPaneBehavior.java:152)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1291)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabHeaderSkin$5.handle(TabPaneSkin.java:1282)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3724)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3452)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1728)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2461)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:273)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:382)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:553)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:925)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/96639997.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1757)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jircclient.FXML.FXMLmainController.onTabCloseEvent(FXMLmainController.java:69)
    ... 53 more
```

**line 69 and 70 FXMLmainController:**

```
System.out.println("FLAG: "+ con.threadExitFlag);
        con.exitThread();
```

Comment: Why not just use `if(con != null)`?

Comment: I dont see you have initialized con.

Comment: My aim is not to just get rid of the exception but actually change something in that object. In other words i need that reference NOT to be null. I don't get why it is null since i pass the reference. If there is any other way i can change that exitThreadFlag from that object, i would like to hear it.

Comment: Variable con is given the reference in the serverController. parentController.con = serverConnection; Doesn't that count as initialization?

Comment: Almas Shaikh i initialized the con object at the main controller and it's working. The problem now is that the thread does not close even the flag is set to true. Any clue why it keeps on going even when i close the socket and then return? That should exit the method startCommunication() inside the thread and eventually dismiss the thread. Am i right?

Comment: When i initialize, the object is a different one and not the one i am passing. I marked the exitThreadFlag as volatile but i still get nullpointerexception...